# Doubt in composition of transpositions.

Tags: permutations

Read article [here](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/833/docs/Abstract_algebra_-_Symmetric_Group.pdf) to show importance of expressing permutation as product of disjoint transpositions.

Have a doubt regarding the notation used. 
*Have found that need an easy way, which is much less confusing*

It states:

Proposition Every permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions. Read the proposition carefully. It doesn’t mention uniqueness at all. Yes, we can write any permutation as a product of transpositions, but not in a unique way. For example $(13) = (12)(23)(12) = (23)(12)(23)$

The paper used an example to show notation (one row) as:

$$\sigma=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 &4 \\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix} \implies (1243)$$

For $(12)(23)(12)$, the corresponding two line permutation  =
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} 
\implies 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Though the paper doesn't state in which order the permutations are processed. But, given the symmetry in processing either from left or right ($(12)(23)(12), (23)(12)(23)$), makes no difference, and choose from right to left.

$$1 \rightarrow 2, 2\rightarrow 3\implies 1 \rightarrow 3; 2 \rightarrow 1$$
The last transposition is $(12)$, while there are elements $3,1$ to be transposed.

So, get:
$$1 \rightarrow 3, 2\rightarrow (1)\rightarrow 2$$
So, get $(13)(2)\implies 1 \rightarrow 3$ or$(13)$.

Next is the rhs product of transpositions : $(23)(12)(23)$, or:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

First transposition on the right end is: $2 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 2$.

The second transposition is $(12), 2 \rightarrow 1, 1 \rightarrow 2$, while there are elements $2,3$ to be transposed from the first transposition.

So, get by composition:
$1 \rightarrow 2, 3 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 3$.

Next, have last composition on the lhs.
$$
1 \rightarrow 3, 3\rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 2
$$

<strike>(The last composition if processed will yield a different answer than $(13)$?)</strike>

*Edit*

Have removed error above, but is there any easy way rather than spending hours ?
In fact, still get confused easily.

Better such an approach be easily programmable, that helps in larger number of transpositions, and number of members in each.

Comment: For one thing you don't have to do them only two at a time. You can begin on one side, keeping track of a given number from cycle to next cycle. If the present number is not mentioned in the next cycle, that number stays as is and you keep going.

Comment: Transpositions are the slowest way to build a permutation so I would expect it to be computationally cumbersome. Such decompositions will almost never be unique, with obvious exceptions being the identity and transpositions.

Comment: @coffeemath Request answer.

Comment: @coffeemath please vet my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "vet my answer"? If it's go through it line by line then I'll pass. You can check it if you know how to calculate them, and if you don't this site isn't one where you can learn that. Use your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Every permutation either a cycle Or product of  disjoint cycles.
2. Any $r$-cycle $(a_1, a_2,...,a_r)$ can be expressed as a product of  $r-1$ transpositions $(a_1, a_r) (a_1, a_{r-1}),... (a_1, a_2) $
3. Any two disjoint cycles commute.

Note: You can also express a $r$-cycle $(a_1, a_2,...,a_r)$  as a product of  $r-1$ transpositions $(a_1, a_2) (a_2, a_3),... (a_{r-1}, a_r) $

So this decomposition is not unique. But number of transpositions for any decomposition is always same.

Method:

For an example choose $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\3&4&5&6&1&2\end{pmatrix}\in S_6$

Step $1$: Write $\sigma$ as product of disjoint cycles.

$$(135) (246) $$

Step $2$ : write cycles as product of transpositions

$$(15)(13)(16)(24)$$

Comment: Nice to add reverse decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

As per response by @coffeemath (and modified it a bit, by adding subscripts, to achieve programmability) on non-unique representation, get for second set of transpositions:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
Have taken, as in post, transpositions from right to left.
$$2_1\rightarrow 3_1, 3_1\rightarrow 2_1$$
$$1_2\rightarrow 2_2, 2_2\rightarrow 1_2$$
$$2_3\rightarrow 3_3, 3_3\rightarrow 2_3$$

Composition 1:
$$2_1\rightarrow 3_1, 3_1\rightarrow 1_2, 1_2\rightarrow 2_2$$
$$2_3\rightarrow 3_3, 3_3\rightarrow 2_3$$

Composition 2:
$$1_2\rightarrow 3_3, 2_1\rightarrow 2_3, 3_1\rightarrow 1_2$$

Here, need keep each transposition intact, if it's subscript number is lesser than other, and no RHS match occurs with a higher subscript LHS.